# javascript redirection doesnt seem to work

Tags: javascript

I use JavaScript for a simple function, however my redirection doesn't work. I thought it was because of the files, but they seem to be in the same folder. See below file structure:

[image]

Here is my relevant code:

```js
function validate() {
  var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
  var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
  if (username == "mr.X" && password == "x123456") {
    alert("Login successfully");
    window.location = "Dashboard.jsp"; // Redirecting to other page.
    return false;
  } else {
    alert("You have inserted wrong credentials");
  }
}
```

Comment: Don't validate passwords in js

Comment: it's just to try

Comment: try `window.location = "/Dashboard.jsp"`

Comment: didn't work anyway

Comment: Is LoginPage.js contains the following code? If it is try `window.location = "/WEB-INF/Dashboard.jsp"`

Comment: does your alert function get triggered ?

Comment: yes it does show them